# drag instead of singleclick/click event triggered on touch devices with a small screen

Tags: javascript, touch, openlayers-3, windows

I'm having problems making custom events that should be triggered by a single click work on touch devices with a small screen (7"). When I'm clicking on the (OpenLayers 3) map, the click is handled as a drag (the map moves very slightly). I suspect that this because the difference between the x/y coordinates of the touchstart and touchend is large enough. However, that is just a gut feeling. Is there anyone that has experienced similar problems? Are there any solutions/workaround known for this problem?

Thanks!